# Http request failing with No Access-control-Allow-Origin flask-restful

Tags: ionic-framework, flask-restful

I am building an api with flask-restful and an ionic/angular mobile app, but requests to the api are failing with the error  "**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.**" even after specifying the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the Resource response.

```
class Auth(Resource):
    def post(self):
        #some code here
        return responseObject,200,{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'}
```

I have tried different browsers and when i check the network XHR calls the response headers don't show the it.

**Content-Length**:90
**Content-Type**:application/json
**Date**:Thu, 14 Sep 2017 11:46:25 GMT
**Server**:Werkzeug/0.12.2 Python/2.7.10

Yet when i use postman to send the requests, i see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

**acccess-control-allow-origin** →*
**content-length** →198
**content-type** →application/json
**date** →Thu, 14 Sep 2017 12:54:52 GMT
**server** →Werkzeug/0.12.2 Python/2.7.10

Anyone with an idea of what is happening, i will be glad to receive your help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have to allow cross origin calls in your API. Have a look here : http://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/